# how to achieve the url pattern when form is submitted

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess

How can I achieve the URL pattern when the form is submitted

### index.php

```
<form name="search_form" method="get" action="search-jobs/">
Skills : <input type="text" name="skills" />
Location : <input type="text" name="loc" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
<br />
```

### .htacess

```
RewriteRule ^search-jobs/(.*)/(.*)?.php$ findjob4.php?skills=$1&loc=$2
```

how can I achieve this url / .htacess aliases when form is submited

**Pattern url**

```
www.example.com/search-jobs/{skills value}/{loc value}.php
```

**sample**

```
www.example.com/search-jobs/php/london.php
```

When i did this, its giving an error as `Object not found` and `Error 404`.
basically : how i get the url pattern in above `Pattern url` in that format and in end of url
`.php` should added

Comment: I think its better if the URL doesn't have `.php` in the end.

Comment: can we acheive that url pattern when form is submitted, irrespective of `.php` in the end. And `.php` is good to have

Comment: No, it's not, you should remove it as well ;)

Comment: An Error occured : 414 Request-URI Too Large and url `http://localhost/example/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/search-jobs/php/london.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set its action to index.php (the same page), and add this to the top of index.php:

```
if (isset ($_GET ['skills'])) {
    header('Location: /search-jobs/' . $_GET ["skills"] . '/' . $_GET ["loc"] . '.php');
}

<form name="search_form" method="get" action="index.php">
    Skills : <input type="text" name="skills" />
    Location : <input type="text" name="loc" />
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
    <br />
</form>
```

You'll also have to remove .php from the rewrite url according to Rafee.

Comment: this code will redirect in loop, till url get exhausted, each and every time url get the values

Comment: No, it won't, since /search-jobs/ is on findjob4.php, different page. (while this code is in index.php)

Comment: if my form is also present in `findjob4.php` then how.. i got the error mentioned above in comment of this question

Comment: What are you saying, the form is both on index.php and findjob4.php? No, that wouldn't work...

Comment: @Jeroen i have tested the above code and its giving an error.  414 Request-URI Too Large

Comment: I've pasted the full code of what should be in index.php, is that what you're using??

Comment: Are you sure /search-jobs/ is being rewritten to a different page then index.php? Because if it isn't, then that's the problem...

Comment: i am using the same .htacess code with `.php` and without `.php`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11766/discussion-between-rafee-and-jeroen)

Comment: @Jeroen its working now!, it was a problem with `.htacess` with `.php` is not working but without `.php` its working perfectly and can you edit your answer or so i can give `up` to your answer

Comment: @SyedHashim if you want to place the same form, then you can, just change the `action="index.php"` and from there `index.php` it will redirect to cleaner url..

Comment: @Rafee: added that to my answer

Answer (score 0):

No need to tinker with any PHP code, just put this code in your $DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess replacing your existing code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+search-jobs/?\?skills=([^&]+)&loc=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search-jobs/%1/%2.php? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^search-jobs/([^/]*)/([^.]*)\.php$ findjob4.php?skills=$1&loc=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

After you verify it's working change `R=302` to `R=301` in first rule.